# MySQL Update Date Column to first date if index already appears in table

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MySQL database (~12 million rows) that contains medical claim data.

Three columns of interest to this question - claim_no, release_date, original_submit_date. Example:

```
claim_no | release_dt | original_submit_date
--------------------------------------------
11111111 | 2017-06-15 | 2017-05-10
22222222 | 2017-06-15 | 2017-06-15
11111111 | 2017-05-10 | 2017-05-10
33333333 | 2017-06-11 | 2017-06-11
```

Where claim_no is an ID for each claim, release_dt is the date the claim was submitted, and original_submit_date is the first date that claim was submitted ( a claim number can appear multiple times in the database due to rebills). In the example, claim 11111111 appears twice, on 2017-06-15 and 2017-05-10. Since 2017-05-10 is the earliest submission date, that is what populates the original_submit_date column.

The database gets updated monthly with a new month's worth of claim submission. This new data has the release_dt, but it won't have the original_submit_date. This needs to be added in based on whether or not that claim number appears in the database already. If it does, then the original_submit_date column needs to be updated to the original_submit_date column from the other appearances. If not, then the original_submit_date column needs to take the value of release_dt.

Ex:

If I add two new rows -

```
claim_no | release_dt | original_submit_date
--------------------------------------------
11111111 | 2017-06-20 | 2017-05-10
22222222 | 2017-06-15 | 2017-06-15
11111111 | 2017-05-10 | 2017-05-10
33333333 | 2017-06-11 | 2017-06-11
11111111 | 2017-06-20 |
44444444 | 2017-06-20 |
```

Then I need a query that will update original_submit_date like this -

```
claim_no | release_dt | original_submit_date
--------------------------------------------
11111111 | 2017-06-20 | 2017-05-10
22222222 | 2017-06-15 | 2017-06-15
11111111 | 2017-05-10 | 2017-05-10
33333333 | 2017-06-11 | 2017-06-11
11111111 | 2017-06-20 | 2017-05-10
44444444 | 2017-06-20 | 2017-06-20
```

Because claim_no 11111111 was already in the database, it took the original_submit_date already on file for that claim - but 44444444 is a new claim, so it took the release_dt from its own row.

The table is indexed on claim_no and release_dt (separately). I've thought about doing a self-join and updating the original_submit_date column if it is null, but that's a strategy I've never used and I'm not sure if it's the most efficient way to go about this, what that query would look like, or if it would even work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The correct (normalized) approach would be to add a new table with `claim_no` as the primary key and the original_submit_date. (You could update that table e.g. with a trigger on your current table.) While this would be the correct approach for all databases, MySQL additionally has the restriction in an `update` statement, you can't directly read from the same table you are trying to update (which would require some resources (e.g. internally copying data to a temporary table) if you would want to write a "selfupdate".

Comment: If you want to keep your current (denormalized) structure (e.g. because you cannot change the rest of your code) you could update the table after you updated the 2nd table, or you use a temporary importtable. Also, you could keep using just one table if you use a trigger on that table, but it will have the disadvantage that you can only update the current row. This means if e.g. an earlier claim would be added later (e.g. you might have a claim twice in your current import, but in the wrong order), the existing date would stay wrong (which is always a potential problem with denormalized data).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - I will try next week and see how it goes.